# How to set default value for select option in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, html

I want select box to have default option. I am using `html` `selected` property. But its not working. I am not having anything in components. I just want selected option to be assigned to `StartingYear`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="StartingYear">
      <option [ngValue]="0" >0</option>
      <option [ngValue]="1" selected>1</option>
      <option [ngValue]="2" >2</option>
      <option [ngValue]="3" >3</option>
      <option [ngValue]="4" >4</option>
</select>
```

Demo link : [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7pjvos?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It is because you are using the `ngModel` as well as the `selected`

Comment: This question has been asked before, refer to the second answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047822/angular-6-html-select-menu-set-default-value

Answer (score 1):

you can set the starting value in the component:

```
  startingyear = 1;
```

The variable in your component and view are not written the same way. Here is the corrected solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8hx96x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Since you're binding your select to a component variable "StartingYear".You need to bind your component value to the initial value you want to set.

If it is a static value then use this code:

```
StartingYear = "1";
```

If its from a service variable then set it like:

```
StartingYear = this.data.StartingYearValue;
```